# On average, how many times will this incorrect loop iterate?

Tags: math, random, for-loop, language-agnostic

In some cases, a loop needs to run for a random number of iterations that ranges from `min` to `max`, inclusive.  One working solution is to do something like this:

```
int numIterations = randomInteger(min, max);
for (int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++) {
   /* ... fun and exciting things! ... */
}
```

A common mistake that many beginning programmers make is to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < randomInteger(min, max); i++) {
   /* ... fun and exciting things! ... */
}
```

This recomputes the loop upper bound on each iteration.

I *suspect* that this does not give a uniform distribution of the number of times the loop will iterate that ranges from `min` to `max`, but I'm not sure exactly what distribution you *do* get when you do something like this.  Does anyone know what the distribution of the number of loop iterations will be?

As a specific example: suppose that `min` = 0 and `max` = 2.  Then there are the following possibilities:

- When `i = 0`, the random value is 0.  The loop runs 0 times.
- When `i = 0`, the random value is nonzero.  Then:

  - When `i = 1`, the random value is 0 or 1.  Then the loop runs 1 time.
  - When `i = 1`, the random value is 2.  Then the loop runs 2 times.

The probability of this first event is 1/3.  The second event has probability 2/3, and within it, the first subcase has probability 2/3 and the second event has probability 1/3.  Therefore, the average number of distributions is

> 0 × <sup>1</sup>/<sub>3</sub> + 1 × <sup>2</sup>/<sub>3</sub> × <sup>2</sup>/<sub>3</sub> + 2 × <sup>2</sup>/<sub>3</sub> × <sup>1</sup>/<sub>3</sub>
>
> = 0 + <sup>4</sup>/<sub>9</sub> + <sup>4</sup>/<sub>9</sub>
>
> = <sup>8</sup>/<sub>9</sub>

Note that if the distribution were indeed uniform, we'd expect to get 1 loop iteration, but now we only get <sup>8</sup>/<sub>9</sub> on average.  My question is whether it's possible to generalize this result to get a more exact value on the number of iterations.

Thanks!

Comment: Poisson, I'm guessing.  But that's a continuous distribution, I'm not sure what the discrete equivalent is...

Comment: @RBarryYoung: It seems to look something like that.

Comment: I think it suffices to only consider the case `min = 0`. Because if `min > 0`, then the probabilities P(i=k) = 0 for k < min, where i is the number of iterations. And the probabilities P(i=k) = P(i=k'), k>=min are obtained by transforming to get k' = k - min, max' = max - min, and min = 0 (i.e. subtract the original min).

Comment: @RBarryYoung, the Poisson is a discrete distribution, not continuous.

Comment: @pjs Right, Poisson is a continuous-time process, but a discrete counted result.  Then I'd say that this is some kind of variable Poisson distribution.

Comment: One problem with Poisson is that Poisson isn't bounded. So the probability of getting 3 iterations in the case max=2 would be greater than zero. So the true probabilities for seeing 0..4 iterations with max=2 are `0.33 0.44 0.22 0.00 0.00`, whereas Poisson with a mean of 8/9 gives `0.41 0.37 0.16 0.05 0.01`. Things seems to get a bit better as you increase max, e.g. for max=4 true = `0.20 0.32 0.29 0.15 0.04 0.00 0.00`, and Poisson = `0.22 0.33 0.25 0.13 0.05 0.01 0.00`. Even with max=10, the approximation isn't great. Bottom line, it's a non-standard distribution (and a v interesting one!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Final edit (maybe!). I'm 95% sure that this isn't one of the [standard distributions that are appropriate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#With_finite_support). I've put what the distribution is at the bottom of this post, as I think the code that gives the probabilities is more readable! A plot for the mean number of iterations against `max` is given below.

[image]

Interestingly, the number of iterations tails off as you increase max. Would be interesting if someone else could confirm this with their code.

If I were to start modelling this, I would start with the [geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution), and try to modify that. Essentially we're looking at a discrete, bounded distribution. So we have zero or more "failures" (not meeting the stopping condition), followed by one "success". The catch here, compared to the geometric or Poisson, is that the probability of success changes (also, like the Poisson, the geometric distribution is unbounded, but I think structurally the geometric is a good base). Assuming min=0, the basic mathematical form for P(X=k), 0 <= k <= max, where k is the number of iterations the loop runs, is, like the geometric distribution, the product of k failure terms and 1 success term, corresponding to k "false"s on the loop condition and 1 "true". (Note that this holds even to calculate the last probability, as the chance of stopping is then 1, which obviously makes no difference to a product).

Following on from this, an attempt to implement this in code, in R, looks like this:

```
fx = function(k,maximum)
{
    n=maximum+1;
    failure = factorial(n-1)/factorial(n-1-k) / n^k;
    success = (k+1) / n;
    failure * success
}
```

This assumes min=0, but generalizing to arbitrary `min`s isn't difficult (see my comment on the OP). To explain the code. First, as shown by the OP, the probabilities all have `(min+1)` as a denominator, so we calculate the denominator, `n`. Next, we calculate the product of the failure terms. Here `factorial(n-1)/factorial(n-1-k)` means, for example, for min=2, n=3 and k=2: 2*1. And it generalises to give you (n-1)*(n-2)*... for the total probability of failure. The probability of success increases as you get further into the loop, until finally, when `k=maximum`, it is 1.

Plotting this analytic formula gives the same results as the OP, and the same shape as the simulation plotted by John Kugelman.

[image]

Incidentally the R code to do this is as follows

```
plot_probability_mass_function = function(maximum)
{
    x=0:maximum;
    barplot(fx(x,max(x)), names.arg=x, main=paste("max",maximum), ylab="P(X=x)");
}

par(mfrow=c(3,1))
plot_probability_mass_function(2)
plot_probability_mass_function(10)
plot_probability_mass_function(100)
```

Mathematically, the distribution is, if I've got my maths right, given by:

[image]

which simplifies to

[image]

(thanks a bunch to http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)

The latter is given by the R function

```
function(x,m) { factorial(m)*(x+1)/(factorial(m-x)*(m+1)^(x+1)) }
```

Plotting the mean number of iterations is done like this in R

```
meanf = function(minimum)
{
    x = 0:minimum
    probs = f(x,minimum)
    x %*% probs
}

meanf = function(maximum)
{
    x = 0:maximum
    probs = f(x,maximum)
    x %*% probs
}

par(mfrow=c(2,1))
max_range = 1:10
plot(sapply(max_range, meanf) ~ max_range, ylab="Mean number of iterations", xlab="max")
max_range = 1:100
plot(sapply(max_range, meanf) ~ max_range, ylab="Mean number of iterations", xlab="max")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some concrete results I plotted with [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/). The X axis is the value `i` reached. The Y axis is the number of times that value was reached.

The distribution is clearly not uniform. I don't know what distribution it is offhand; my statistics knowledge is quite rusty.

#### 1. min = 10, max = 20, iterations = 100,000

[image]

#### 2. min = 100, max = 200, iterations = 100,000

[image]

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I wasn't sure so I plotted them both. If you take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution, at the top right image, you can see that for the blue curve (which is roughly how a poisson distribution with the same mean as the distribution above would look, allowing for min=100), you can see the Poisson is pretty much symmetric and has almost zero probability for the lowest number of iterations, not like we have here. Also, you would need to calculate the mean to parameterize the Poisson distribution? (It's 111.3 here, but you don't know that up front.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it would still, given a sufficient amount of executions, conform to the distribution of the `randomInteger` function.

But this is probably a question better suited to be asked on [MATHEMATICS](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I suspect not.  Consider if min was 1 and max was 5.  You would expect that 20% of the runs would result in 5 iterations of the loop.  With the incorrect implementation, the only way you would get 5 iterations would be if 5 was chosen as the random number 5 times in a row.  The chances of that would be significantly less than 20%.  This makes me think that the number of iterations would be skewed significantly toward the lower bound.

Comment: That would depend on the distribution of the function and how many times you let it run. Mathematically I think my statement holds true. Proability in theory and in computer implementations don't always match - since computers seldom use true randomness...

Comment: @fredrik- I just updated my answer with a counterexample that disproves your claim - the average number of iterations in one specific instance is not equal to the average number of iterations that would be chosen given a single choice.

Comment: @fredrik - Just noticed that my reasoning is wrong - 5 would not have to be chosen 5 times in a row, but still I would suspect the number of iterations to be skewed to the lower end.

Comment: Personally I think it works well for computing _and_ mathematics. I enjoyed this a lot, and approached it from a code-first point of view. It would be interesting to see how true mathematicians approach it -- rather differently from us I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know the math behind it, but I know how to compute it! In Haskell:

```
import Numeric.Probability.Distribution

iterations min max = iteration 0
  where
  iteration i = do
    x <- uniform [min..max]
    if i < x
      then iteration (i + 1)
      else return i
```

Now `expected (iterations 0 2)` gives you the expected value of ~0.89. Maybe someone with the requisite math knowledge can explain what I’m actually doing here. Because you start at 0, the loop will always run at least `min` times.

Comment: Cool!  That matches the value of 8/9 I computed in the example. :-)